# Cannot convert object of type ListViewSubItem into derived class

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a ListView in my VB.NET GUI application containing information about files (name, path, size).

With normal usage of `ListViewItem` and `ListViewSubItem` everything works fine. But I need some extra information in the `ListViewItems` and `ListViewSubItems`. So I created 2 derived classes from the ListViewItem and `ListViewSubItem` classes:

**MyListViewItem**

```
Public Class MyListViewItem
    Inherits ListViewItem

    ' additional information
    Public m_MyAdditionalInfo As String = Nothing
End Class
```

**MyListViewSubItem**

```
Public Class MyListViewSubItem
    Inherits ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem

    ' additional information
    Public m_MyAddtionalInfo As String = Nothing
End Class
```

With these classes I try the following code but get an error message:

```
Private Sub TestMyClasses()
    Dim x As New MyListViewItem
    x.m_MyAdditionalInfo = "listviewitem"
    x.Text = "x"

    Dim y As New MyListViewSubItem
    y.m_MyAddtionalInfo = "listviewsubitem"
    y.Text = "y"

    x.SubItems.Add(y)

    ListView1.Items.Add(x)

    Dim z As MyListViewSubItem = Nothing

    ' conversion causes an error
    z = CType(x.SubItems.Item(0), MyListViewSubItem)

    MsgBox(z.m_MyAddtionalInfo)
End Sub
```

> Cannot convert object of type "ListViewSubItem" into type "WindowsApplication1.MyListViewSubItem".

*"WindowsApplication1" is just my demo app where I created the derived classes.*

During compilation everything is fine. Just on runtime the code throws this error. So my question is why I am getting this error message?

Comment: Without actually answering, would you consider using the Tag property to store your extra info and prevent you having to handle a new subclass?

Comment: Ultimately, I think your Cast/Ctype is attempting to narrow the scope, which I believe will throw the Invalid cast.

Comment: Assuming each subitem is a bit of info about one file (ala Explorer), then additional info on a subitem is info about info (meta data).  If you are wanting to add info the user doesnt see, just add subitems which do not have columns - the data is there, but not displayed.

Comment: I think this will cause some problems when adding more columns and wondering of "unknown" data is showing up (especially when someone else alters the code). In addition I then have to add some algorithm to map my hidden data with the visible.

Comment: @Mort: this is indeed what I need to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the fact that the SubItem at index 0 is actually the ListViewItem itself. You need to grab the item at index 1 in order to convert to your MyListViewSubItem class.

```
z = CType(x.SubItems.Item(1), MyListViewSubItem)
```

Also, as Mort said, if you only need to store one additional string with your ListViewItem/ListViewSubItem, you may look into using the Tag property.

Comment: Here's the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems) for what THerzog has correctly stated: "The first subitem in the ListViewItem.ListViewSubItemCollection is always the item that owns the subitems. When performing operations on subitems in the collection, be sure to reference index position 1 instead of 0 to make changes to the first subitem."

Comment: With this knowledge I do not even need to cast the item into my subclass. Also makes my algorithm easier when only looping through SubItems and get all information. Perfect solution for my question.

However, I will use the Tag property instead of the derived class.